# Finding the smallest $x$ given a set of congruence conditions.

Tags: congruences

> Find the smallest integer $x$ such that
>
> $$x \mod 5 = 3\\ x \mod 7 = 4\\ x \mod 9 = 6$$

Can you tell me how to solve this type of question? I don't need a solution.

---

Clearly  the smallest $x$ for the first one is $8$. The smallest $x$ for the second one is $11$. And for the last one it is $12$. Since $12$ is the highest of the three solutions, the $x$ I am looking for must be greater than or equal to $12$. However, $12 \mod 7 = 5 \not = 4$, so $x$ cannot be $12$ as it does not fulfil the second condition.

Technically, I can keep on going up and up until I find a fitting number for the three conditions, but I doubt that's how I am supposed to do this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: The smallest for the first is $3$, not $8$  For the last, $12$ is not a solution, $6, 15$ are

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, which may help motivate the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Start with $x=3$, which satisfies the first equation.  We can add as many $5$'s to it as we want without spoiling the first equation.  Now look at the second.  We need $x=3+5k\equiv 4 \pmod 7$ For small numbers like this, you can just think $3,8,13,18$ and notice that $18 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$  Now we not to spoil $\pmod 5$ and $\pmod 7$, so we have to add multiples of $35$.  We need $18 + 35 m \equiv 6 \pmod 9$  Since the right is a multiple of $3$, so must the left be, so $m$ must be a multiple of $3$ an we need $18+105n \equiv 6 \pmod 9$.  $n=1$ works and our answer is $133$.  The solutions will recur (though we weren't asked for this) at $5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9=315$

Comment: Did you mean $123$ instead of $133$?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make factors that "disappear" modulo the other numbers.  So, one answer will be the following:

$$
x = 
3 \cdot (7\times 9)(7 \times 9)^{-1}_5 + 
4 \cdot (5\times 9)(5 \times 9)^{-1}_7 + 
6 \cdot (5\times 7)(5 \times 7)^{-1}_9
$$
Here, $(y)_m^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $y$ mod $m$.  So, for example, 
$7\times 9 = 63 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$, and $3 \times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, so $(7 \times 9)^{-1}_5 = 2$.

The solution to this problem is unique modulo $5 \times 7 \times 9$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem: find $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ such that
 $$
\begin{matrix}
    7\cdot 9b_1 = 1 \pmod{5} \\
    5\cdot 9b_2 = 1 \pmod{7} \\
    5\cdot 7b_3 = 1 \pmod{9} 
\end{matrix}
$$

Then,
$$
   3\cdot 7\cdot 9b_1+4\cdot 5\cdot 9b_2+6\cdot 5\cdot 7b_3 \pmod{5\cdot7\cdot9}
$$
is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$x \mod 5 = 3, \qquad x \mod 7 = 4, \qquad x \mod 9 = 6$$

These numbers are small enough that we can solve by inspection.

$x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \implies x = 3+5t$ where $t$ is an integer. So we search for the first integer of the form $3+5t-4$ that is a multiple of $7$.

$$4, \quad 9, \quad \color{red}{14}$$

Since $14+4=18$, we have $x = 18 + 35t$.

So we search for the first integer of the form $18+35t-6$ that is a multiple of $9$.

$$12, \quad 47, \quad 82, \quad \color{red}{117}$$

Since $117+6=123$, we have $x = 123$.